# Trouble with making background of image transparent in python using pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, transparent

I have a rather confusing problem in running our game. I am trying to make a game using Python's pygame and I am using images downloaded from the internet. The problem is that some images have a white background and some have a colored background. I used Photoshop to get rid of the white background and re-saved the image. However, when I ran the simulation in Python, it gave me the original picture with the original background. This is slightly perplexing to me.

Here's the part of the code using pygame I used to implement the image:

```
        self.image = pygame.image.load("jellyfishBad.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the .convert_alpha() method when loading the image for per pixel transparency.

So,

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("jellyfishBad.png").convert_alpha()
```

Answer (score 0):

load the image `self.image = pygame.image.load("jellyfishBad.png")`

set colour key. `self.image.set_colorkey(white)`

convert to alpha. `self.image(white).convert_apha()`

Set the colour key first and then convert to alpha.